# React Native and build.gradle

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

I am new to React Native and I work with a colleague on a new app. I created a new react native project which has generated a .gitgnore file as well. In it all the .gradle files (and thus the build.gradle file inside /android/ folder) are ignored.

When I pushed the project to Github and my colleague pulled, he `npm install` to download the node_modules (which are also excluded <- I have read the rational behind this) and then he run `react-native run-android`. This failed. We realised that if he creates the build.gradle file inside /android/ and copy-paste the contents of my build.gradle which I have locally (as is ignored by git) everything runs smoothly.

My main questions are: 
1) Should the build.gradle file be ignored as react native does by default? 
2) If yes, how are teams supposed to work on a react native project if they somehow need to get the build.gradle contents to run the project on their side?
3) What happens if my disk drive fails? I can pull everything from git but I will not have the build.gradle. Should I right it from scratch?

The contents of the .gitignore file:

```
# OSX
#
.DS_Store

# Xcode
#
build/
*.pbxuser
!default.pbxuser
*.mode1v3
!default.mode1v3
*.mode2v3
!default.mode2v3
*.perspectivev3
!default.perspectivev3
xcuserdata
*.xccheckout
*.moved-aside
DerivedData
*.hmap
*.ipa
*.xcuserstate
project.xcworkspace

# Android/IntelliJ
#
build/
.idea
.gradle
local.properties
*.iml

# node.js
#
node_modules/
npm-debug.log
yarn-error.log

# BUCK
buck-out/
\.buckd/
*.keystore

# fastlane
#
# It is recommended to not store the screenshots in the git repo. Instead, use fastlane to re-generate the
# screenshots whenever they are needed.
# For more information about the recommended setup visit:
# https://docs.fastlane.tools/best-practices/source-control/

*/fastlane/report.xml
*/fastlane/Preview.html
*/fastlane/screenshots

# Bundle artifact
*.jsbundle
```

Answer (score 3):

It is `.gradle` file in `.gitignore` and not the `*.gradle` or `build,gradle`.

So the answer to your questions is `build.gradle` is not ignored and should not have to be ignored.

The android related things included in .gitignore are:

```
build/
.idea
.gradle
local.properties
*.iml
android/gradle.properties
```

For standard, you can refer to this below two sample .gitignore file.(you can replace your .gitignore contents with the below link contents and can check.)

[enter link description here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/.gitignore)
    https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/.gitignore
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/local-cli/templates/HelloWorld/_gitignore

Comment: I am afraid that although your logic seems correct, I still somehow have the problem. Unless I explicitly ask the default gitignore not to ignore it (i.e., !android/build.gradle), it ignores it. I tried it in a fresh project. What am I missing?

Comment: Can you add your .gitignore file content? So I can try to help you in that case.

Comment: Uploaded the gitignore file.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check in your `build.gradle` files, only the `.gradle` directory should be ignored.

Comment: The react native's genarated .gitignore ignores it. Is it wrong?

Comment: I think it's wrong. It didn't do so in my apps and I have some custom code in it, which is needed by other devs to build.

Comment: It's September 2021 today, and RN includes `android/gradle.properties` file in git. https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android said to put some credentials like `MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_PASSWORD` in `android/gradle.properties`. Does anyone know if this practice is secure? I disagree with putting plain passwords in any git-checked file.